# How to add a class to a specific stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use [CSSStyleSheet.insertRule()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet/insertRule) to insert a new class inside a specific stylesheet. That stylesheet has the id "customStylesheet" for example.

[This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet) says "A specific style sheet can also be accessed from its owner object (Node or CSSImportRule), if any.". However I can't figure out how to access that specific stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is fairly straight forward.

```
var sheet = document.getElementById('customStylesheet').sheet;

sheet.insertRule('.someclass {display: none;}'); // was missing a ' here
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rdcsv9s/23/) showing it working. I have updated the fiddle to show it working on a style tag in the head also.

Comment: Wow, it STILL won't work on my side... what is up with that? Your method should work with a normal style tag, right?

Comment: Yes it should work on a normal style tag. I updated the fiddle.

Comment: Seems like no matter what I do, it just won't work. Maybe it's something with codepen.io? Anyway, you technically answered my question, since it clearly works in your jsfiddle, so I'll give you that one.

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately. :( However, no worries, I found out I can just use JQuery's .text to achieve the same result, so I'm good. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with no jQuery. Say that you wished to set everything with the class `purpleText` to `color: purple`. First, you would get the stylesheet using `document.styleSheets[_index_].ownerNode.sheet`. Next, use the `insertRule()` method. The parameter is just a string holding the CSS code, as in `".purpleText{color: purple}"`. So, for the first stylesheet, the whole command would be `document.styleSheets[0].ownerNode.sheet.insertRule(".purpleText{color: purple}");`

Comment: Does not really address getting a particular style sheet by id. Also there is no need to get the sheet with `document.styleSheets[0].ownerNode.sheet` when `document.styleSheets[0]` is the style sheet.

Answer (score 0):

To get a styleSheet by ID, use this:

```
document.getElementById('stylesheet').sheet;
```